# Pyspark: reshape data without aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, contingency

I want to reshape my data from 4x3 to 2x2 in pyspark without aggregating. My current output is the following:

```python
columns = ['FAULTY', 'value_HIGH', 'count']
vals = [
    (1, 0, 141),
    (0, 0, 140),
    (1, 1, 21),
    (0, 1, 12)
]
```

What I want is a contingency table with the second column as two new binary columns (`value_HIGH_1`, `value_HIGH_0`) and the values from the `count` column - meaning:

```python
columns = ['FAULTY', 'value_HIGH_1', 'value_HIGH_0']
vals = [
    (1, 21, 141),
    (0, 12, 140)
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot` with a *fake maximum aggregation* (since you have only one element for each group):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy('FAULTY').pivot('value_HIGH').agg(F.max('count')).selectExpr(
    'FAULTY', '`1` as value_high_1', '`0` as value_high_0'
).show()
+------+------------+------------+
|FAULTY|value_high_1|value_high_0|
+------+------------+------------+
|     0|          12|         140|
|     1|          21|         141|
+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Nice one. But, can't we achieve this without aggregating, as a requirement from him?

Comment: @Prazy I am not aware that spark or even sql has such a syntax. There's always an aggregation involved when pivoting -

Comment: @Psidom in this case you can pass in `values = [0,1]` as a second argument to [`pivot`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot), which is more efficient.

Comment: @pault Good call -

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` and `pivot` is the [natural way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103592/5858851), but if you want to avoid any aggregation you can achieve this with a `filter` and `join`

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.where("value_HIGH = 1").select("FAULTY", f.col("count").alias("value_HIGH_1"))\
    .join(
        df.where("value_HIGH = 0").select("FAULTY", f.col("count").alias("value_HIGH_1")),
        on="FAULTY"
    )\
    .show()
#+------+------------+------------+
#|FAULTY|value_HIGH_1|value_HIGH_1|
#+------+------------+------------+
#|     0|          12|         140|
#|     1|          21|         141|
#+------+------------+------------+
```