# How to do data transpose using pyspark, no aggregation, but just reshape

Tags: pyspark

Again, sorry for asking stupid question, I'm new to Pyspark.
I'm trying to transpose my dataset from:

```
   id   dif BA  AB
   1    1   100 30
   1    2   200 40
   1    3   300 20
   1    4   100 15
   2    1   99  18
   2    2   89  9
   3    1   29  20
   3    2   70  32
   3    3   39  13
   4    1   24  14
   4    2   56  23
   4    3   24  26
   5    1   27  31
   5    2   30  17
   6    1   100 19
```

to become

```
    id  BA1 BA2 BA3 BA4 AB1 AB2 AB3 AB4
    1   100 200 300 100 30  40  20  15
    2   99  89  NaN NaN 18  9   NaN NaN
    3   29  70  39  NaN 20  32  13  NaN
    4   24  56  24  NaN 14  23  26  NaN
    5   27  30  NaN NaN 31  17  NaN NaN
    6   100 NaN NaN NaN 19  NaN NaN NaN
```

In python, I used the following code and it works.

```
df['AB_idx'] = 'AB' + df.dif.astype(str)
AB = df.pivot(index='id',columns='AB_idx',values='AB').reset_index()

df['BA_idx'] = 'BA' + df.dif.astype(str)
BA = df.pivot(index='id',columns='BA_idx',values='BA').reset_index()

df1=pd.merge(BA, AB, on='id', how='left')
```

Now the problem is I have to translate into pyspark again since I have more than 1 billion records.
any thought? thanks

I do see some example like this post:

[Pyspark: reshape data without aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103269/pyspark-reshape-data-without-aggregation)

But it seems do not work for me, since I have more than 100 different dif values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try pivot with agg as `first` and then rename the columns:

```
output = (df.groupBy("id").pivot("dif")
         .agg(*[F.first(i).alias(i) for i in ["BA","AB"]]).orderBy("id"))

d = dict(zip(output.columns,[''.join(i.split('_')[::-1]) for i in output.columns]))
output.select(*[F.col(k).alias(v) for k,v in d.items()]).show()
```

---

```
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|BA1|AB1| BA2| AB2| BA3| AB3| BA4| AB4|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|100| 30| 200|  40| 300|  20| 100|  15|
|  2| 99| 18|  89|   9|null|null|null|null|
|  3| 29| 20|  70|  32|  39|  13|null|null|
|  4| 24| 14|  56|  23|  24|  26|null|null|
|  5| 27| 31|  30|  17|null|null|null|null|
|  6|100| 19|null|null|null|null|null|null|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```